# Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined on reaction - even though reaction is made but it fails to collect

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined on reaction - even though reaction is made but it fails to collect.

It does the embed & reacts as normal, but it never collects the reaction via DM

```yaml
Collection [Map] {}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined
    at E:\New Project - 2020\SocialMisty\lib\Handlers\ToSAgreementHandler.js:30:38
```

```js
msg.author.send(embed).then(async function (message) {
        message.react('✅').then(r => {
            message.react('❎');
        });
        message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == who.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == '❎'),
            {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000
            }).then(collected => {
                console.log(collected)
                if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
                    message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Thanks`).then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
                    message.delete();
                } else {
                    message.channel.send(`${message.author}, You **MUST** agree to the ToS.`).then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
                    message.delete();
                }
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e) // gets emoji error here.
                message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Please type in here again to recieve the ToS again.`).then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
                message.delete();
            });
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e) // doesn't get the error here
        this.postToRelayChannel(client, message.author, where);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know this was from a year ago. But just in-case some people come across this in v13:

```js
await message.awaitReactions({ filter, max, time })
    .then(collected => {
        if (collected.size === 0) return;

        // code
    })
```

Since `collected.first()` returns `undefined`, it means there is nothing in the map (`collected`). We can use the [`Map.prototype.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) variable to check if the length/size of the map is empty. This seems to work perfectly for me as of v13, I haven't had this error since.